# Create table does not work

Tags: sql, mariadb, create-table

I have a problem with creating a table in `Maria DB Server.`

I could successfully make the table on my other device, but for MYSQL (with probably different code).

**Query:**

```
CREATE TABLE admin (
    'id' double(9999) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
    'username' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    'passcode' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    'email' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    'state' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    'points' double(9999) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(id) 
);
```

**Query Error:**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near "id' double(9999) NOT NULL auto_increment 'username' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 'pa' at line 2

If any other information is required ask in comments.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were putting single quotes around the table names, which MariaDB was interpreting as string literals.  Instead, just use the unquoted names directly:

```
CREATE TABLE admin (
    id double(9999) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    passcode VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    state VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    points double(9999) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

If you do need to *escape* a column name in MariaDB/MySQL, e.g. because the name has whitespace or is a keyword, you can do so using *backticks*:

```
CREATE TABLE admin (
    `id` double(9999) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ...
)
```

But note that putting whitespace into column or table names, or using reserved keywords, is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

You could also put the PRIMARY KEY right after AUTO_INCREMENT

```
CREATE TABLE admin (
    'id' double(9999) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    'username' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    'passcode' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    'email' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    'state' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    'points' double(9999) not null

);
```